# Maximize a part programmatically in E4 RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am looking for a way to maximize and minimize/restore a part programmatically in an E4 RCP application. Currently, one has to double-click on the part title tab to achieve this operation.

(By default, Eclipse IDE uses the Ctrl+M shortcut to do that. Ideally, I'd like to use the same keyboard shortcut.)

Answer (score 1):

After examining the RCP model state after maximizing a part (more precisely, a part stack), it seems the easiest way is to add a "Maximized" tag to the stack that contains the part that needs to be maximized.

As seen in MinMaxAddon.subscribeTopicTagsChanged(), the changes in the following tags are monitored, and presentation changed accordingly: "Maximized", "Minimized", "MinimizedByZoom".

Comment: Best to stick to the constants for these values found in `IPresentationEngine`